# How to delete a date from pandas date_range

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

So I have a pandas date_range like so

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2005-1-1', end='2014-12-31', freq='D')
```

I want to remove all the extra days resulting from leap years.

I do a for loop

```
for each in index:
    if each.month==2 and each.day==29:
        print(each) # I actually want to delete this item from dates
```

But my problem is that I don't know how to delete the item. The regular python list methods and functions doesn't work.
I've looked everywhere on SO. I've looked at the documentation for [pandas.date_range](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html?highlight=pandas%20date_range#pandas-date-range) but found nothing

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to use drop to remove the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(start='2005-1-1', end='2014-12-31', freq='D')

leap = []
for each in dates:
    if each.month==2 and each.day ==29:
        leap.append(each)

dates = dates.drop(leap)
```

Comment: Thanks. Masking works good. Never came to mind. You have any idea why matplotlib fill_between will not work for pandas date_range as index. keeps giving me this ufunc error.

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating two Series objects to store the months and days separately and use them as masks.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2005-1-1', end='2014-12-31', freq='D') #All dates between range
days = dates.day #Store all the days
months = dates.month #Store all the months

dates = dates[(days != 29) & (months != 2)] #Filter dates using a mask
```

Just to check if the approach works, If you change the `!=` condition to `==`, we can see the dates you wish to eliminate.

```
UnwantedDates = dates[(days == 29) & (months == 2)]
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2008-02-29', '2012-02-29'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Very good solution @Rakesh. Perhaps if one wants just dates could be a bit faster using the generator.

Comment: @Parousia, this __vectorized__ solution should be faster compared to list comprehention / generator / etc.

Comment: @Parousia, As a general rule, when working with pandas and DataFrames, I avoid writing a loop at all costs. Vectorized solutions are far more efficient.

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan, thanks for pointing that out. Thing is I'm new to pandas and I'm coming to grips with the fact that it has a steep learning curve. I know about vectorized solutions in name only. If you know of any good tutorial on that subject please do share a link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
dates = dates[~dates['Date'].str.contains('02-29')]
```

In place of `Date` you will have to put the name of the column where the dates are stored.

You don't have to use the for loop so it is faster to run.